# How to upload a file to a table using a modal and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I have a dynamic table which allows a person to upload an image, their name and surname within a modal when they click a button. When I try upload the image my table displays "undefined" in the place of the image. How do I get the table to display the image?

I've tried using .val(), .attr('src'). I am new to jquery so I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake here, but I'm out of ideas and can't seem to find a similar issue anywhere.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#save_btn").click(function () {
        let image = $("#Image").attr('');
        let name = $("#Name").val();
        let surname = $("#Surname").val();
        $('#myTable').append(
            '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + image + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + name + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + surname + '</td>' +
            '<td> <button id="edit" class="btn btn-sm material-icons" style="color: green"> create </button> </td>' +
            '<td><button id="delete" class="btn btn-sm material-icons" style="color: red">delete</button></td>' +
            '</tr>'
        );
    });
    
    });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <title>Homework 2</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add to Table</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <table id="myTable" class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Image</th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Surname</th>
            <th scope="col">Edit</th>
            <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Data to Table</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="Image_input" for="Image" class="col-form-label">Image:</label>
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="name_input" for="Name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label id="surname_input" for="Surname" class="col-form-label">Surname:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Surname">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="save_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I made a change to the append function. I added this...

```js
"<td>" + "<img id='table_image' alt='' src='" + './images/' + image + "' > " + "</td>" +
```

Comment: Could it be this? `let image = $("#Image").attr('')` . All the other variables are `.val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

     $('input[type="file"]').change(function(e){
               fileName=URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
            });
        $("#save_btn").click(function () {
            //let image = $("#Image").attr('src',fileName);
            let name = $("#Name").val();
            let surname = $("#Surname").val();
            $('#myTable').append(
                '<tr>' +
                '<td><img src="' + fileName + '" width="150" height="150"></td>' +
                '<td>' + name + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + surname + '</td>' +
                '<td> <button id="edit" class="btn btn-sm material-icons" style="color: green"> create </button> </td>' +
                '<td><button id="delete" class="btn btn-sm material-icons" style="color: red">delete</button></td>' +
                '</tr>'
            );
        });
        
        });
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <title>Homework 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add to Table</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table id="myTable" class="table table-dark">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Surname</th>
                <th scope="col">Edit</th>
                <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Data to Table</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="Image_input" for="Image" class="col-form-label">Image:</label>
                            <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="name_input" for="Name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label id="surname_input" for="Surname" class="col-form-label">Surname:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Surname">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="save_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Surely I can't use the same ID for 2 separate variables?

Comment: you want to get image name or image preview?

Comment: I want the image preview to display in the row

Comment: then check my answer it is useful to you

Comment: Is that pure Jquery or is it JS and Jquery? 

I did see it but the top half looks like JS and I can't use JS for this project 

Comment: I think you have to use FileReader api to load image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209073/discussion-between-jinesh-and-nihilus-js).

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning blank attr value. Please see updated code as below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#save_btn").click(function() {   
    var fileNameIndex = $("#Image").val().lastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
    var image = $("#Image").val().substr(fileNameIndex);    
    let name = $("#Name").val();
    let surname = $("#Surname").val();
    $('#myTable').append(
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + image + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + name + '</td>' +
      '<td>' + surname + '</td>' +
      '<td> <button id="edit" class="btn btn-sm material-icons" style="color: green"> create </button> </td>' +
      '<td><button id="delete" class="btn btn-sm material-icons" style="color: red">delete</button></td>' +
      '</tr>'
    );
  });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <title>Homework 2</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add to Table</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <table id="myTable" class="table table-dark">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Image</th>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          <th scope="col">Surname</th>
          <th scope="col">Edit</th>
          <th scope="col">Delete</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>


  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Data to Table</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="Image_input" for="Image" class="col-form-label">Image:</label>
              <input type="file" class="form-control" id="Image">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="name_input" for="Name" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label id="surname_input" for="Surname" class="col-form-label">Surname:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Surname">
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button id="save_btn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```